# Python - How to create a list from csv file that has different row lengths?

Tags: python, csvreader

I have a .csv file with 105 rows and 9 columns. Some of the rows only have values in four columns.
How can I create a list from the .csv file without getting an IndexError: list index out of range?

```
from elements import Element
import csv

filename = "elements.csv"
fields = []
elements_list = []

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    fields = next(csvreader)

    for row in csvreader:
        elements_list.append(Element(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]))
```

When I run this it gives IndexError: list index out of range

Example of the .csv file:

```
Element,Number,Symbol,Weight,Boil,Melt,Density,Vapour,Fusion,
Aluminum,13,Al,26.98,2723.16,933.16,2700,284.34,10.68,
Silicon,14,Si,28.09,2953.16,1683.16,2330,170.02,46.48,
Phosphorus,15,P,30.98,
Sulfur,16,S,32.06,717.76,392.16,2070,12.60,1.42,
Chlorine,17,Cl,35.45,238.46,172.16,1560,10.22,3.22,
Argon,18,Ar,39.95,87.36,83.76,1400,6.53,1.18,
```

For example, how can I create a list that fills the last missing 5 values of "Phosphorus" to "0"
As in:

```
Silicon,14,Si,28.09,2953.16,1683.16,2330,170.02,46.48,
Phosphorus,15,P,30.98,0,0,0,0,0,
Sulfur,16,S,32.06,717.76,392.16,2070,12.60,1.42,
```

Comment: Have you looked into using pandas? I would strongly recommend checking out https://datatofish.com/import-csv-file-python-using-pandas/#:~:text=Steps%20to%20Import%20a%20CSV%20File%20into%20Python,path.%20...%203%20Step%203%3A%20Run%20the%20Code if you haven't done so. pandas can read and handle csv's to the degree that you've stated here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to pad a row to a desired width.

```
width = 9
row = (row + [0] * width)[:width]
```

As an aside

```
Element(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8])
```

Is better written as

```
Element(*row)
```

or if `row` is longer than you need, do

```
Element(*row[:9])
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I thought this was about dicts; there's no `get` for lists :(

---

You can utilize the built in [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```py
from elements import Element
import csv

filename = "elements.csv"
fields = []
elements_list = []

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    fields = next(csvreader)

    for row in csvreader:
        elements_list.append(Element(row.get(0, 0), row.get(1, 0), row.get(2, 0), row.get(3, 0), row.get(4, 0), row.get(5, 0), row.get(6, 0), row.get(7, 0), row.get(8, 0)))
```

Though for reading csv files I would recommend you to look into [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), as it is more powerful and was built for this.

Comment: `csv.reader` yields lists.  Lists do not have a `.get()` method.

Comment: You are correct!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use `pandas`, one option is to read by line and then split each row thereafter.

```
import pandas as pd
elements = pd.read_csv("elements.csv", sep = "\n")
elements = elements[0].str.split(",", expand = True)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use pandas library to read csv
Pandas is very much easy than this
Filling data is very easy in pandas